# How to send a context in a view based on class

Tags: python, html, django

i am trying to send a context to a view bassed on class as i said in the title.

This is my class view:

```
class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    templates = Templates.objects.get(isSelected=True)
    model= settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = "register/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

I want to send 'templates' to a context and then to the html. But i dont know how to do it.

Anyone can help me? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any class-based view, if you want to add additional context data you do so in the `get_context_data` method.

```
class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = "register/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['templates'] = Templates.objects.get(isSelected=True)
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!. One question, i have tried to use get_query_set with the context_object_name variable. But it doesnt work, you can tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. Another way to do that is by using `view` object.
In that case you don't need to override `get_context_data()`.

```
class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = "register/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def templates(self):
        return Templates.objects.get(isSelected=True)
```

And inside your template use:

```
{{ view.templates }}
```